# How to fit pretrained yolov4 model to other class?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision, yolo

I have already trained model for one class, so I have weights and how can i train it for second class? This model detects cars 100% and I need it to detect vehicle plate number, I used yolov4, darknet framework and google colab, please could someone show me as a code? I can send the code file.
I ran training by this line:

```
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov-4-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map
```

In my google disk I have file with wieghts.